# PostgreSQL - Why a privileged user can't access newly created partition

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

Why a privileged user can't access newly created partition?

PostgreSQL version: 10.0

Suppose my PostgreSQL sever has a user called `app` with following permissions:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO app;
GRANT USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public to app;
```

Now this user `app` can do select, insert and update action for "existing" table/partition (for example: `mytable_partition_old`) just as my expectation, everything goes well so far.

However, a `master` account creates a new partition of a table after the `GRANT` command above by following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "mytable_partition_new" PARTITION OF mytable FOR VALUES IN('some_value');
```

After `mytable_partition_new` is created, the user `app` got "permission denied for this relation" by executing `INSERT INTO mytable_partition_new values (...)` command.

I understand it can be resolved by issue `GRANT SELECT, .... TO app` again.
My question is if there any better way to achieve it?

(we don't have a dedicated DBA and got stucked in this situation for a while..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GRANTs you have shown, only granted the privileges for *existing* objects. To grant the privileges for "future" objects, you need to [alter the default privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html):

```
alter default privileges in schema public
  for role master
  GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON TABLES TO app;

alter default privileges in schema public
  for role master
  GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCES TO app;
```

The above will only affect *future* objects, so for the tables (or partitions) you have already created, you need to re-run you original GRANT statements once again.

Comment: Thank you! So if I run both `GRANT ... TO app` and the statements you provide **in the first time**, then I got both *existing* and *future* objects for `app`, am I correct?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe could you share what is the exactly command? (sorry for postgresql newbie

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I don't want my account `app` has master role

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: thanks, added. I didn't see the master role in the question.

Comment: what's the difference between your original answer (without `for role master`) and the new one (with `for role master`) @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @MengChengWei: it applies all those grants for the master role, rather than for the current role

Comment: Got it, so if I run those sql commands in master account, I can just omit `for role master`, correct?